# WCF request-response pairs with HTTP/2 and ajax calls

Tags: ajax, wcf, http2

I have a WCF service on windows, with IIS 10.
A webapp called this service with ajax, and the webserver (nginx) is HTTP/2.

In the service and also the webapp I have identifiers for both the response and the request, and the request accept only the answer, that contains there id. In the WCF service is simply an = mark between the request.id ant the newly created response.id

The strange tings happened when the webapp fast enough to sent the request at the same time, when this occurs, the WCF service send back the reposnse of another request.
(I try different concurency modes, locks in code, and some things I found in google, but nothing really works)

I can't really understand how and why can it happened.

Please suggest me some solution, or try to find the root case of it.

Comment: Whether there is a callback function in your WCF service, if there is a callback function, the WCF server will call the client's method, which may cause other responses to be returned.

Comment: Also, what is the binding used by your WCF?